# Taking a piece of a REGEX and setting it to a String

Tags: c#, regex

Is there any way to take a part out of a regex? Let's say I have a match for this

```
\s*(string)\s*(.*\()\s*(\d*)\)\s*;?(.*)
```

and I want to change it like this

```
Regex.Replace(line, @"\s*(string)\s*(.*\()\s*(\d*)\)\s*;?(.*)", "$1 $2($3)  // $4", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Is there any way I can grab the `$4` by itself and set it equal to some `string` variable?

Let's say the regex match is: `string (55) ;comment`

In this case I'd like to get the word `comment` only and set it to a string without going through the String.Split function. Ultimately, though, I'd just like to get the digits between the parentheses.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Can you provide an example input and output?

Comment: I made an edit with more explanation

Comment: An example of the desired output would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 2):

There's an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149475%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the `Replace` method which takes a `MatchEvaluator` delegate:

```
string pattern = "...";
string result = Regex.Replace(line, pattern, m =>
{
    int digits = 0;
    string comment = m.Groups[4].Value; // $4

    int.TryParse(m.Groups[3].Value, out digits); // $3

    return string.Format("{0} {1}({2})  // {3}", 
        m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[2].Value, digits, comment);
}, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if I understand the question correctly:

```
var re = new Regex(@"\s*(string)\s*(.*\()\s*(\d*)\)\s*;?(.*)");

var match = re.Match(input);

if (match.Success)
{
    int i = match.Groups[4].Index;
    int n = match.Groups[4].Length;
    input = input.Substring(0, i) + replacementString + input.Substring(i + n);
}
```